# when i have used django-tabbed-admin for django 2.0...version...i am getting the error 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python-3.x

AttributeError at /admin/polls/employee_detail/add/

'str' object has no attribute '**name**'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/polls/employee_detail/add/
Django Version:     2.0.4
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:

'str' object has no attribute '**name**'

Exception Location:     /home/rashesh/myproj/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tabbed_admin/admin.py in parse_fieldsets_inlines_from_tabs, line 104
Python Executable:  /home/rashesh/myproj/myvenv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.5.2
Python Path:

['/home/rashesh/myproj',
 '/usr/lib/python35.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload',
 '/home/rashesh/myproj/myvenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 10 Apr 2018 09:49:28 +0500

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are compatibility issues between django-tabbed-admin and Django 2.x
Someone has suggested a fix but the maintainer has not yet adopted it.

You can check out this link for more details.
https://github.com/omji/django-tabbed-admin/issues/23

Perhaps you can use the suggested solution from "ogtony" to fix your problem.
Hopefully, the maintainer will update the package soon.

Answer (score 0):

[July 2018]

Yaay!, it seems Omji (the maintainer) is working on it now. I can see a commit on github just 2 hours ago.  I haven't tested it yet but i hope it works for  you. Check it out.

https://github.com/omji/django-tabbed-admin

...
[Updated Aug 2021]

It has been over 3 years and it seems Omji has abandoned the project. Meanwhile, Django has now moved from version 2.0 to 3.0 . I recently found a free Django Admin Theme that has tabs and more. Plus, it is compatible with the newest version of Django. I am posting it here in case someone is looking for a similar solution. It is called django-jazzmin

https://pythonrepo.com/repo/farridav-django-jazzmin-python-administrative-interfaces

Disclaimer: I am NOT affiliated to django-jazzmin.

Answer (score 0):

Per the above comments, it sounds like the latest release (**1.0.4**) fixes this issue.
https://github.com/omji/django-tabbed-admin/releases/tag/1.0.4

Comment: Can you add more details? Because such a answer is considered as a low quality post.

Comment: The above mentioned pull request was merged by the maintainer and a new version was pushed to pypi containing that fix (1.0.4). The submitter should version bump to confirm.